# Android MissingFormatArgumentException error

Tags: android

after some debug application without any change on source code i get this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1s'
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.169 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**i dont have any**

1. String.format on all of my source code
2. formatted string on string.xml

after clear project, restart `ADB`, restart `pc` problem dont resolve.

i'm wondering whats problem, because on log i dont have any class name or some description which cause of this error

[image]